# What is the best algorithmic way to find power of a binary valu where base and power both are binary?

Tags: algorithm, math, binary

Suppose the problem is 1010^1110 then how to come up with a fastest solution algorithmically?

I got such a formulation ((1010^2)^2)^2 * (1010^2)^2 * 1010^2

Comment: Any number can be expanded as sum of power of 2. Thus, your conversion relies on that. In result polynom multiplication will mean exponent and summation will mean multiplication in final expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Decimal powers**

You may want to expand your number by powers of 2. This will be possible since any natural number can be expanded as sum of power of 2. For example, you may use:

```
function getPowersOf2($number)
{
   if(!$number)
   {
      return [];
   }
   $p = floor(log($number, 2));
   return array_merge([$p], getPowersOf2($number-pow(2, $p)));
}
```

-to generate that sequence. For `14` it will be `8 + 4 + 2`, so `2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1`, and, as the result, `[3, 2, 1]`. Then you'll be able to use this like:

```
function getPower($base, $number)
{
   $result = 1;
   foreach(getPowersOf2($number) as $pow2)
   {
      $temp = $base;
      while($pow2--)
      {
         $temp*=$temp;
      }
      $result*=$temp;
   }
   return $result;
}
```

-so each power will produce one multiplication in final expression and each multiplication will also produce one multiplication. For example, if original power is  `14` that will be `8` operations, since:

```
(x^14) = x^(8+4+2) = x^(2^3+2^2+2^1) = (((x^2)^2)^2)*((x^2)^2)*(x^2)
```

**Binary powers**

It's hard to say that it is "optimization" - look into `getPowersOf2()` function - inside there are logarithms at least. But in your case your powers are already converted. `1110` means `1*2^3 + 1*2^2 + 1*2^1 + 0` - it's by radix definition. Thus, you may perform your multiplication in a very simple way:

```
function getPowerBin($base, $number)
{
   $m = count($number)-1;
   $result = 1;
   foreach($number as $bin)
   {
      if($bin)
      {
         $temp = $base;
         $pow2 = $m;
         while($pow2--)
         {
            $temp*=$temp;
         }
         $result*=$temp;
         $m--;
      }
   }
   return $result;
}
```

-so you'll just iterate through power's binary presentation (array in my case) and look into current power `$m` - getting same result as in function above.

This *may be* useful because it will produce less multiplications, but I doubt that it can be called *optimization* - because it will use many additional things inside. But in terms of how many times we'll multiply our base - yes, it will win.